# Setting up SMTP for php mail

Tags: php, email, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail)

Im a newbie programmer and im try to do a software that includes sending confIrmation through email. Im using WAMp server and using Php as my language. I know i have to setup an my smtp so i can send emAils but i have no idea how to do it. Im using windows 7 64bit os. Hope someone can give me a step by step tutorial of this. Thank you!

Comment: please search before posting this has been asked and answered dozens of times

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good walkthrough of how to do this:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

The one key here is that if you want to use a local SMTP server, you either have to have one running (doubtful) or you should install one of the test ones available for this type of use.

If you need a SMTP server test tool, I use the Free SMTP Server tool from this site:

http://www.softstack.com/

It is free, easy to use, and simple.  For development, I can't ask for more.

Comment: How will i know what domain and port i put in it? Im sorry im really a newbie

Comment: If you use a SMTP testing tool, you will set the port there.  Usually the port is 25.

Comment: I tried what the website you gavesaid in the walkthough, but when i test the mail() fnction it still says failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini ...

Comment: Nevermind i got it. Thank you so

Answer (score 0):

Installing [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#644) is the easiest way to setup a LAMP stack on Windows. It comes with an SMTP server.

Comment: Does installing xampp mean i have to replace wampp server?