# Why is my PHP script not sending emails when set from header

Tags: php, sendmail, email-headers

I have a php script that is only sending mail when the user registration.
I put in something along the lines of:

```
$to ='testmail@gmail.com';
$message  = 'Hello';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Website <admin@example.com>\r\n";
if($results= mail($to, 'User Registration', 'Test', $headers)) {
  echo 'success';
} else {
  echo 'fail';
}
```

But the email doesn't send on server. When i put the following line :

```
$headers .= "From: Website <admin@example.com>\r\n";
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you checked spam folders?

Comment: check for the logs in `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: try `$headers .= "From: admin@example.com\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the answer to [smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail) it's very similar a question to yours?