# What will be the settings in php.ini for sending an email?

Tags: php, email

It causes the following error related to a mail server or `php.ini` file.

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in E:\wamp\www\pr\mail.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in E:\wamp\www\pr\mail.php on line 15

Comment: [From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email with PHP from an SMTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have a mail server setup somewhere. For that, you need the Hostname, port (usually 25), and possibly username and password. Google for example offers SMTP services ([Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)), but you can use other servers if you have.

The error tells you that you don't have a mailserver setup on your machine, or it does not listen to the 25 port. If it's a shared hosting, you need to call the hosting company to assist you with this. If it's a dedicated server, then you may want to install a mailserver on that machine.  If you don't want to install a mailserver, you can use Google or other provider, and you'll have to follow the steps provided here: [smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail) or in the other link above