# How to make PHP Mail() function use a specific SMTP server?

Tags: php, email

How do you make php's mail function send email from a specific separate SMTP server instead of using the local host?

My code:

```
<?php
$to = "user@AOL.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";


$headers .= 'From: <noreply@foo.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

---

*Background info:*
I currently have a Linux server running Apache and also acting as a mail server (foo.com) and a separate server (bar.com) running a LAMP stack.

On bar.com I am trying to code a auto mailer for users registering accounts that sends the emails from foo.com.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` does not support smtp. You need to use a mail framework which supports smtp like: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

See: [smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail)