# PHP and the mail() function

Tags: php

I am using a PHP script to send e-mails to a list of friends.  This used to work successfully but now the only e-mails that are sent successfully are those inside my domain ("mycompany.com").  Any e-mails outside my domain fail to be sent.  Is this a problem with permissions?  Could I fix it by changing the headers I use when I call the mail() function?  Here is the PHP script:

```
$name = "Joe Smith";
$email = "jsmith@mycompany.com";
$to = "ajones@mycompany.com, tom@abc.com, ted@def.com, mary@ghi.com";
$subject = "Dinner Invitations";
$message = "Invitation to Dinner";
$headers  = "From: ".$name."<".$email.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Only ajones@mycompany.com was sent out by the server.  tom@abc.com, ted@def.com, and mary@ghi.com did not get sent.

Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: did you check the spam folder? they must be there

Comment: I don't have access to the spam folder.  And I don't have access to a log of errors.  I am hoping for suggestions so I can pass them on to the server admin.

Comment: You are a little short on details, as any one of a hundered things could have changed in the downline processing that is involved in sending mail, not least being the mail admin blocking mail to unknown address's

Comment: This may be blocked either in the client, your server, or any of the relay servers inbetween. A server can be configured to 'allow' sending mails for a specific domain. The receiver of a mail may check this by sending a verification to the domain. Anyway, without proper access to at least the spam folder and the PHP/Apache error logs, and without checking the result of the `mail` function, you're basically blindfolded.

Comment: if email is received on one id, rest of them must receive the email as well..

Comment: Can you send mail to these other addresses using the companies standard mailing client?

Comment: This really could be anything.  Let somebody check your server's mail log.  It should give you hints as to why your mails fail to be delivered.  Maybe your server caught some malware and started to send spam, so other servers stopped trusting your server?

Comment: I was told by the server admin that some "maintenance" was done on the server, but he didn't think it would affect sending e-mail.  All I know is the server is not sending e-mails to anyone outside my domain.  I was hoping there might be a header variable that would allow me to request permission to send e-mails outside my domain.

Comment: I think you need to connect to a valid mail server via SMTP to send mail. Almost receiver's server blocking mail from unknown address (which was configured in your php.ini). More detail on sending SMTP mail is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail

Comment: I will ask the admin to check the error logs.  He's pretty busy and I was hoping to offer suggestions that would speed up his investigation of the problem.