# why my bug free code not sending email

Tags: php, email

Hy everyone!
I am following one tutorial to learn that how can we reset our password in php.
 I am working as localhost.I write the code, code is bug-free, error reporting is also on, mail() function is also working but i am receiving not any email.
Also, on entering an invalid username, it is not giving any error too.
I read out and tried all methods but no any method helped me !
Please check it out that where i am doing wrong !
Thanks.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    set_error_handler("var_dump");

    require_once './include/db_connection.php';
    if (isset($_POST['button'])){
        $db_email="";
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email =$_POST['email'];
        $query="select * from signup where username='$username'";
        $result   = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        // If the count is equal to one, we will send message other wise display an error message.

        if($count>0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $db_email = $row['email'];
            }

            if($email == $db_email) {
                $code = rand(1000, 10000);
                $to =$db_email;
                $subject = "Password Reset Link";
                $body = "Do not reply of this automated email."
                      . "Enter the below link to reset passwowrd "
                      . "http://localhost/Validation/forgotpassword.php?code=$code&username=$username";

               // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
               $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
               $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

               // More headers
               $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
               $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

               mysqli_query($link, "update signup set paareset='$code' where username='$username'");
               if(mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)) {
                  echo 'Good';   
               } else {
                  echo 'mail() not working';
               }
               echo 'Check your inbox';

            } else {
                echo 'You have an incorrect email';
            }
        }

    }
?>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <label> Enter your User ID : </label>
        <input  type="text" name="username" /><br>
        <label> Enter your Eamil address : </label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" /><br>
        <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />    
</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your mailserver set up correctly?

Comment: @DanielMensing
What do you mean by mailserver?
I am sending an eamil to gmail

Comment: Stating that your code is "bug free" is a pretty brave thing to do. You _never_ can be 100% certain of that.

Comment: @arkascha Well if the code is bug free, they dont need us, we can move on to something we can fix!

Comment: @RiggsFolly :-) Unfortunately that is not true. "Bugs" are not the only reason someone might need help...

Comment: @arkascha
i agreed with you. Theen what's the solution to my problem then?

Comment: I see one bug! `</form>` is places after `</body>`

Comment: I see two bugs! There is no `<DOCTYPE`

Comment: Do you get the `Good` message or the `mail() not working` message

Comment: @RiggsFolly
I am getting Good message

Comment: Remember, the `mail()` function does not actually send the mail, all it does is pass the mail request to a actual mail server. Depending on how that mailserver is setup, you probably have to send _from_ a valid email address that exists on that (your) mailserver.

Comment: The yahoo/google/hotmail mail servers are getting much more selective about what they consider VALID mail. Your mail server may also require a valid SPF record etc or mail may just be bounced. You might only know about the bounce if you were looking at CatchAll email address on your mail server.

Comment: If you are a Windows user, then you definitely dont have a mail server by default.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't set up any mail servers. You can always test your code with smtp4dev (https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) to be sure you even send an email.

If you do want to send emails to any email account you have to set up mailservers: [smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail)

EDIT: You can't send emails with PHP without smtp servers.