# Sending SMTP Emails from PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I'm a bit stuck here. I have some websites hosted on TSOHosts. I use the php mail() function to send the occassional email, e.g. from a contact form.
The emails have stopped working, and nobody at the hosting provider seems to be capable of fixing it.
They say I should use SMTP emails. OK, I get that, they point me to this article on how to do it:
https://www.lifewire.com/send-email-from-php-script-using-smtp-authentication-and-ssl-1171197

So I write the script (below) and, it doesnt work:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "NoReply@mysite.org.uk";
$to = "me@myemailaddress.co.uk";
$subject = "Hi port 465";
$body = "Hello World";
$host = "ssl://mail3.gridhost.co.uk";
$port = "465";
$username = "username@mysite.org.uk;
$password = "Testing123";

$headers = array (
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail))
{
echo "<p>".$mail->getMessage()."</p>";
}
else
{
echo"<p>Message successfully sent!</p>";
}
```

I also have a port 25, non-ssl script, that also doesnt work.
When I say doesnt work, its not throwing an error, just no email arrives (checked in spam).

The hosting company first asked me where the Mail.php is as referred to by the require_once "Mail.php" line
The article suggests that this should be installed on php4+ (Im using 5.6.37)

This is remarkably similar to this article:
[smtp configuration for php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525818/smtp-configuration-for-php-mail)

But I am stummped as to how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have an email address at NoReply@mysite.org.uk? Remember this will have to actually be an email account on the host.

Comment: You are missing a closing quote on the email address, line 8.

Comment: The missing quote is my mistake when I edited the script to remove real address etc.

Comment: Yes I do have an actual Email account on the hosting that works for the $username and $password Ive used.

Comment: I have stumbled across the reason. I logged into the webmail client provided by the hosting company using the $username and $password in the script, and as expected I got the inbox, however what I now see is some routing failures. It turns out that the $to address I was trying to use was using a forwarder e.g. me@mydomain.com > myactualemail@gmail.com. when I changed the $to address to be myactualemail@gmail.com it worked first time! I hope this insight helps someone else.